# Show that $\hat{f}$ is integrable over $\mathbb{R}$ and $\int_E f$=$\int_{\mathbb{R}} \hat{f}$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

> Let $f$ be integrable over $E$. Define $\hat{f}$ to be the extension of $f$ to all of $\mathbb{R}$  obtained by setting $\hat{f}$$\equiv 0$ outside of $E$. Show that $\hat{f}$ is integrable over $\mathbb{R}$ and $\int_E f$=$\int_{\mathbb{R}} \hat{f}$.

This is a problem from Royden 4th edition.
I am unsure how to proof this problem. We know $f$ is integrable over $E$. And we have thm. $26$ in the book that has the condition $h\equiv0$. However, I think I may need to use the Vitali's convergence theorem instead? A complete proof or concrete steps are appreciated.

Comment: I think you mean integrable in the sense of Lebesgue's definition for integration. Right?

Answer (score 3):

First, let's show that $\hat{f}$ is Lebesgue integrable on $\mathbb{R}$. Consider the set $E_{\alpha} = \{ x\in \mathbb{R}: \hat{f}(x) \geq \alpha\}$ for $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$. We have two cases

$$\alpha \leq 0: E_{\alpha} = \{ x\in \mathbb{R}: \hat{f}(x) \geq \alpha\} = (\mathbb{R}\setminus E) \cup \{x\in E: f(x) \geq \alpha\}$$

$$\alpha > 0: E_{\alpha} = \{ x\in \mathbb{R}: \hat{f}(x) \geq \alpha\} = \{x\in E: f(x) \geq \alpha\}$$

So, it's Lebesgue measurable for any $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$. This shows that $\hat{f}$ is integrable on $\mathbb{R}$. A simple calculation shows that

$$\int_\mathbb{R} \hat{f} = \int_{\mathbb{R}\setminus E} \hat{f} + \int_E \hat{f} $$

The first term in the RHS is zero. Also, the second term is equal to $\int_E f$. Therefore
 $$\int_\mathbb{R} \hat{f} =  \int_E f $$

Comment: For $\alpha\leq 0$ Why does $E_\alpha = \left(\mathbb{R}\setminus E\right)\cup\{x\in E:f(x)\geq\alpha\}$ I don't really see it.

Comment: @Wolfy  Let's say $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Either $x\in E$ or $x \in \mathbb{R}\setminus E$. If $x \in E$, then $\hat{f}(x)=f(x) \geq \alpha$. If $x \in \mathbb{R}\setminus E$ then we have $0 \geq \alpha$. Right? So, if $\alpha > 0$, the second set is empty. While if $\alpha \leq 0$, the second set is all of $\mathbb{R}\setminus E$. Right?

Comment: I got it thanks

Comment: @Wolfy You're welcome.